# how to query mongodb when you list of values

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to find a mongodb query for the below document. Find all the documents that has this guid 360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7 but the guid can be in 1st node or any node in the contactlists.values.

The sample below query doesn't work when the guid is in 2nd or 5th node.

db.Contacts.find(
{

```
    "Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.0.Value": "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}"
}
```

)

```
{ 
"_id" : BinData(3, "ZLz5ddW2pUCpYg4R+8XWgA=="), 
"Identifiers" : {
    "IdentificationLevel" : NumberInt(2), 
    "Identifier" : "user1@gmail.com"
}, 
"Personal" : {
    "FirstName" : "user1", 
    "Surname" : "user1"
}, 
"Emails" : {
    "Preferred" : "Preferred", 
    "Entries" : {
        "Preferred" : {
            "SmtpAddress" : "user1@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}, 
"Lease" : null, 
"Tags" : {
    "Entries" : {
        "ContactLists" : {
            "Values" : {
                "0" : {
                    "Value" : "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}", 
                    "DateTime" : ISODate("2021-10-08T21:42:30.731+0000")
                }, 
                "1" : {
                    "Value" : "{4D90C25F-F0BE-47C0-EB6E-CA799B25E91B}", 
                    "DateTime" : ISODate("2021-10-08T21:52:04.355+0000")
                }, 
                "2" : {
                    "Value" : "{6DC40CA8-AC78-404C-C5D3-1E868E1D8EB4}", 
                    "DateTime" : ISODate("2021-10-08T21:52:26.156+0000")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is using aggregations

- Make the objects to array using `$objectToArray`
- Check whether it has the value using `$match`

here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "objToArray": {
        "$objectToArray": "$Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "objToArray.v.Value": "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      objToArray: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eCj1JJU30Ee)**

Comment: it isn't working please check this sample https://mongoplayground.net/p/aVRIb7TfLtg

Comment: Its working. You are not passing corect formatted documents. Check my answer,i put a demo. Or you can directly check in mongodb

Comment: varman, thank you it is working within the mongodb and not in mongoplayground for some reason. The only last issue I am seeing email id is unique identifier and there are no duplicate documents in the collection but I am getting duplicate records, is there anyway we can add distinct ?

Comment: Yes. We can. But post ur document in mongo playground and remove unwanted fields and show me what is ur expected result

Answer (score 0):

if your `values` is an array, use `$`

```
"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.$.Value": "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}"
```

If it Is embedded document, you can only enumerate all.

Maybe you can try enumerate up to 100 item.

```
"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.0.Value": "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}",
"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.1.Value": "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}",
"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.2.Value": "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}",
"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.3.Value": "{360DC2AE-2B67-4E8D-E320-71D0D30D90F7}"
```

Comment: Its not really an array and it is embedded document, please see full document trying db.Contacts.find({}, {"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.$.Value": "{4D90C25F-F0BE-47C0-EB6E-CA799B25E91B}"}) didn't work with an error Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Positional projection 'Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.$.Value' does not match the query document.

Comment: db.Contacts.find({}, {"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.0.Value": "{4D90C25F-F0BE-47C0-EB6E-CA799B25E91B}"}) using this works but it pulls only items that has this value at 0th position but not if it is 1st or 2nd position.

Comment: it is not actually mean  `0th position` but a normal field name call `0` in your structure, I think you save your data in wrong way and it will make your query very difficult.

Comment: Values can have upto 8000 nodes so enumerate 8000 times in the query is not feasible and I can't change structure it is product based and comes out of a software. Any help like wild card or contains etc and we have 6 million objects